# About Erlang function, especially the function's identifier

Tags: erlang

I have a question about Erlang function. See the code in Erlang shell:

> ```
> 1> F1 = fun() -> timer:sleep(1000) end.
> #Fun<erl_eval.20.111823515>
> 2> F2 = fun() -> io:format("hello world~n", []) end.
> #Fun<erl_eval.20.111823515>
> ```

**F1** and **F2** are different, but why are they both having an identifier `#Fun<erl_eval.20.111823515>`? And what do these magic numbers mean?

---

There is a paragraph in [ERTS Manual](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/crash_dump.html#id79001), says:

```
When interpreting the data for a process, it is helpful to know that anonymous
function objects (funs) are given a name constructed from the name of the
function in which they are created, and a number (starting with 0) indicating
the number of that fun within that function.
```

I also can not catch the meaning of this paragraph, can you please explain it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't read too much meaning into the names of anonymous functions. All you can safely get out of it is the name of the module in which they were created. You can try counting funs in the module to find which one but I wouldn't bother.

That being said, there is a reason why both of the funs have the same name. Expressions entered in the shell are not compiled but are evaluated by the interpreter in the module `erl_eval`. This module has one fun for interpreting funs of each arity. So there is one fun in `erl_eval` for funs of arity 1, `#Fun<erl_eval.20.111823515>`. Hacky, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the same functions in a module (lets not think of shell right now)

```
-module(fun_test).
-export([test/0]).

test() ->
    F1 = fun() -> timer:sleep(1000) end,
    F2 = fun() -> io:format("hello world~n", []) end,
    {F1,F2}.
```

Output is as follows

```
1> fun_test:test().
{#Fun<fun_test.0.78536365>,#Fun<fun_test.1.78536365>}
```

In the above example the anonymous function objects F1 and F2 names are constructed using the name of the module fun_test, unique identifier 0 and 1 (incremental for each function in the module), return addresses etc. as defined in the [ERTS Manual](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/crash_dump.html#id79001). This explains the paragraph mentioned in the manual. Though not very useful, the function numbering is handy during debugging as `-test/0-fun-1-` in the trace will tell you that anonymous function 1 in test/0 function is the source of the error.

For the functions defined in the shell use erl_eval module as explained by rvirding. The result of function object declaration is the return of erl_eval for that arity. So always the same value is returned for that arity.